# iphone delayed response from server

Tags: iphone, ios, request, nsurlconnection, response

As soon as, I send request to the server (via `NSURLConnection` `sendSynchronousRequest` method), the server receives it in about 2 seconds, it processes and sends back response in another 3-5 seconds. However, I only get back the response in 30-35 seconds. This delay makes our communication very slow.

Even the async APIs are getting a delayed response.

Earlier, everything was working fine, with client getting the response back within 10 seconds.
Anyone else having this issue? What could be the reason?

**EDIT**
here is a screenshot of `Wireshark` analysis:

[Link](http://i45.tinypic.com/28ldetw.png) to a better image

[image]

How should I see what packet is saying what?..and why is it getting delayed?

**EDIT2**
Here is the code:

```
 NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nsURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:180.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:180.0];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sdata] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSError *error= nil;

NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error ) {
    NSLog(@"error sending synchronous request: %@", error);
}
NSLog(@"request completed with code:%d",response.statusCode);
```

Comment: Put code here for better understand

Comment: check your network...may be ur network issueee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution** that worked for me:

In the request headers, iOS sets "gzip" for "Accept-Encoding" by default. The gzip compression was taking a lot of time, and hence the delayed response. I did the following to solve the problem:

```
[theRequest setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

NOTE: Check your headers, for any response delay.

Thanks to @occulus for directing me to the request headers!

Comment: A quick question, does this mean gzip compression is removed only for request not for response? I believe so, but would like to be confirmed :)

Comment: NO. setting this in the request header ensures no gzip compression in the whole connection (not even in the response).

Comment: What if the response is big then? May I ask for the average size of the response in your case? :) I may encounter the same issue, so I would like to get better understanding to make a decision on if i should set it in header too.

Comment: it varies. can't say it for sure. but u can assume it to be some small MBs

Comment: thanks, i got it. I will pay attention to the delay first then make a decision :)

Answer (score 8):

I'd avoid calling `sendSynchronousRequest`. Use the asynchronous version instead if you're not doing the call already on a background thread (you don't want to block the UI thread).

How do you know when the iOS response is received? An NSLog? A UI state change?

See also these questions:

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest - background to foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975818/nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequest-background-to-foreground)

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest taking too much time to respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516653/nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequest-taking-too-much-time-to-respond)

**Update**

If you're a bit stuck, one strategy might be to rule out the use of `NSURLConnection` as the problem.

- **Strategy 1:** try using `NSURL`'s asychronous connection call instead of synchronous
- **Strategy 2:** try using a different HTTP lib, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

If you want to take a closer look at what is going on with the HTTP connection, you can use tools such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to debug what data is being sent and received. To get the most benefit from this sort of analysis, you need to have some knowledge of the HTTP protocol(s). This is probably more time consuming than the previously mentioned strategies.

See also questions such as [How to monitor network calls made from iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128362/how-to-monitor-network-calls-made-from-ios-simulator).

**Update**

Are you accessing a webserver of your own, or is it someone else's?

Have you had a close look at the headers being sent to your webserver (and the ones being returned)? Pay attention to the content length, for example. Wrong content length can cause a delay, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290075/nsurlconnection-nsmutabledata-for-file-downloads-is-really-slow).

To see the request and returned headers, you could use Firebug, or something like wget or curl on the command line.

Also, double check that there's not a newline on the end of your URL, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625201/348476).

Comment: i am doing NSLog just before the `sendSynchronousRequest` and just after that. I am doing sendSynchronousRequest in a background thread, so I assume, it's equivalent to async version.

Comment: Ah ok. What happens if you use a browser or wget/curl to get the same data? Is it ok?

Comment: I tried using **Strategy1**, async api by Apple (`NSURLConnection`), but its the same delay.
Also, I tried using Charles, m not getting how to use it. :(
Will try Strategy2, and let you know.

Comment: I completely disagree with the comment on sync/async calls. This might block the UI, ok, but it can not introduce the delay, especially if run on background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You do this over wifi or celluar?

Speaking from my experience, when my data useage is exeeded my phone-provider slows down my downloads. Sometimes this happen to me at the end of the month after I did use a lot of mobile data.

Comment: its wifi with unlimited data usage plan

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to say but it may be network problem  first check it. it proper or down ?? okay Maybe I will be  wrong.. but first check it...

**Following describe code it might solve your problem :)**

```
NSString *url = @"Your URL ";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
.
.

    /// Add Here Your    NSMutableData Valuew 
.
.
[request setHTTPBody:body];
 NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (theConnection)
{
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
else
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed!");
```

Comment: network was the first thing I checked. There's nothing with the network. will try ur code

Answer (score -1):

To ease your problems with asynchronous HTTP Request you should consider using the AFNetworking framework

Comment: This is simply not true, AFNetworking is based on NSURLCOnnection